# Send data as multipart/form-data

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, multipartform-data

I have .NET Core back end, that receive DTO as form-data.

Here is controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromForm] RegisterDto model)
    {
        var result = await _authAppService.Register(model);
        if (result.Code == 409)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Ok(result.Token);
    }
```

Here is DTO

```
 public class RegisterDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PasswordConfirmation { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string GcmToken { get; set; }
}
```

I need to send data from Angular app via form-data

I defined model at Angular side

Here is it

```
export class RegisterDto{
Email: string;
Password: string;
PasswordConfirmation: string;
FirstName: string;
LastName: string;
```

}

And this is how I try to do form-data sending

```
register(){
  const formData =  new FormData();
  formData.append(this.registerObject);
```

}

in append method I have this erroк

> Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)

How I can send DTO via form data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append the whole object without giving it a field name. As the error says it acceptes 2-3 arguments however you are only providing one argument without giving it a field name.

```
register(){
     const formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('regObj', this.registerObject);
}
```

however it's good if you append each field as formdata value such as.

```
formGroup: FormGroup;
formData: FormData;

register() { 
    this.formData.append('Email', this.formGroup.controls.Email.value);
    this.formData.append('Password', this.formGroup.controls.Password.value);
    this.formData.append('FirstName', this.formGroup.controls.FirstName.value);
    this.formData.append('LastName', this.formGroup.controls.LastName.value);

    // call your service and send it
}
```